# jquery .click event not working with image in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

My end goal here is to get my image, which is being used as a button, to run a .js function when it is clicked.

my background.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="content_info.js"></script>
 </head>
</html>
```

the part of my content_script.js that creates the image

```
function addbutton(position, name) {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("icons/donate.png");
    element.setAttribute("type", "image");
    element.setAttribute("src", imgURL);
    element.setAttribute("class", "addressbuttons");
    element.setAttribute("id", name);
    position.parentNode.insertBefore(element, position.nextSibling);
}
```

and my content_info.js

```
console.log('info loaded');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).live('click', '.addressbuttons', function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Whenever I click the image, nothing happens. this setup appears to work [here](http://jsbin.com/akiwo/862) with [source](http://jsbin.com/akiwo/862/edit), so im not sure why its not working for my extension.

**EDIT:** I have now also tried using .on() and wrapping everything in $(window).load, with no change.

Comment: Have you tried using .on() as the element is added dynamically? Also, why don't you just put the image and content in with HTML and CSS rather than js?

Comment: @Coop I have tried the .on(), but with the same results. I am using the .js to add the image after certain words or phrases, and didn't think it was possible to do with HTML and CSS.

Comment: Last thing I can think of would be to try using .on() and wrap it all in $(window).load instead of $(docoument).ready

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in 1.7 & removed completely in 1.9. You have to use `on()` instead.

Comment: @Krishna, see me and Coop's above comments. I have tried using .on(), but thanks for letting me know that .live() is depreciated

Comment: @Coop, just tried with no effect. thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: is this working? `console.log('info loaded');` also write another `console.log` statement inside document ready. is that working?

Comment: @Krishna, yes info loaded is working. I just tried adding in another one after $(document).ready and that one works as well.

Comment: weird. I can't think of anything other than looking for typos or looking in the DOM if the element has actually been created. A jsfiddle with this problem reproduced would be nice to help you.

Comment: Please add you manifest.json to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some help from a friend.

my content_info code needed to be in the content_script.js, and I needed make jquery.js web accessible in the manafest.json

After doing both of those, everything works as expected